How to find the device path for a USB cash drawer on Windows and open it with a button click in Laravel?
I am building a POS solution in Laravel and need to integrate a USB cash drawer. I am facing difficulties finding the device path for the USB cash drawer on Windows 10 and making it open with a button click.
My Questions:

How can I find the device path for the USB cash drawer on Windows 10?
Once I have the device path, how can I adjust my Laravel controller to open the cash drawer via a button click?

I understand that on Windows, devices are typically assigned to COM ports like COM3. However, I am unsure how to identify and use this in my PHP script correctly. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Here is what I have so far:
Controller Code:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CashDrawerController extends Controller
{
    public function open()
    {
        $device = "/dev/ttyUSB0"; // Adjust based on your actual device path
        $command = chr(27) . chr(112) . chr(0) . chr(25) . chr(250); // Example command

        if (file_exists($device)) {
            $fp = fopen($device, 'w');
            if ($fp) {
                fwrite($fp, $command);
                fclose($fp);
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Cash drawer opened.']);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Failed to open device.'], 500);
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Device not found.'], 404);
        }
    }
}

Route Definition:
Route::get('/open-cash-drawer', [CashDrawerController::class, 'open'])->name('open-cash-drawer');

JavaScript for Button Click:
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#openDrawerBtn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('open-cash-drawer') }}',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response.message);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseJSON.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>


Is the php code even going to be running on  the same machine that the USB device is connected to? Normally your php code would run on a central server and each (I guess?) till would be a separate client device with a browser which talks to that server. If that's your setup then the php code would never be able to even see the USB device because it's on another machine. And a web app running in the browser is sandboxed and can't connect to local hardware either. If this is your application's design you may need to reconsider, and think about having a native client app on the till

Are you sure this problem is related to AJAX after all?
